# Load image from folder inside project

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm making an app with the folder like image below:
 [image]

As you can see in this picture, Stickers folder have 2 sub folder "1" and "2". In side them is bunch of icon and I wanna load it in a collection view with each sub folder is a package of different sticker. For more details, please see this picture:
[image]

So, how can I get it in my project folder? I've read about access document directory but seem like it not solve my problem.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to load images from the application bundle. If you can share a sample project I can help you, else please search for loading images from application bundle

Comment: @MidhunMP It's hard because this is private SDK of my company so I can share my project. So sad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at `Filemanager`s API. It offers all you need.

Example to get content at path:

```
let pathToDir1 = Bundle.main.resourcePath! + "/Stickers/1";
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let contentOfDir1 = try! fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: pathToDir1)
```

Example to iterate over:

```
let docsPath = Bundle.main.resourcePath!
let enumerator = fileManager.enumerator(atPath:docsPath)
let images = [UIImage]()
while let path = enumerator?.nextObject() as! String {
    let contentOfCurDir = try! fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path)
    // do whatever you need.
}
```

For details see Apples [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/filemanager) and [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/ManagingFIlesandDirectories/ManagingFIlesandDirectories.html).

Comment: As your answer if I should create 2 path for 2 sub folders then get it specifically to 2 arrays?

Comment: In this example, yes.  But `FileManager` offers way more. Additional example added.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to access an image within your project folder you simply need to use the image name. You don't need to define the whole path.

**Objective-C**

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithName:@"IMAGE_NAME"];
```

**swift**

```
var img = UIImage(named:"IMAGE_NAME")
```

Comment: I mean load all folder as an array then populate it in a collection view. Sorry for confuse question. I'll edit my question